# Server Side Filtering for JQuery Datatables plugin to mimic the built in client side filtering

Tags: jquery, filter, server-side, datatables

The client side filtering (built in) for DataTables plugin is really nice. It will filter your results based on your search words, word by word on any field.

The example Server Side code provided searches the entire string against any field. How would I modify this

```
$sWhere = "";
if ($_GET['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch']) . "%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```

to achieve what i'm looking for?

So far i've tried renditions of the following:

```
$sWhere = "";
if ($_GET['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    $words = explode(" ",$_GET['sSearch']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($words); $j++) {
            if($words[$j] != "") {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($words[$j]) . "%' OR ";
            }
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```

with no luck at all. I would assume I just need to loop through all the 'words' in the search string and search each column against those. Now i'm losing myself with the logic. I am searching all fields for all words, i just need to group them via AND and OR in such a way that if i have the following table

```
  |col1  |  col2  |  col3
  -----------------------
#1| aaa  | bbb    |  ccc
#2| aaa  | ddd    |  xxx
#3| hugo | aaa    |  rap
```

and i search for "aaa bbb" I only return result #1 and not all three. 
I know this is simple.. however i've been racking my brain on it so much i've lost myself.

Comment: Answered my own question. See below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my new Server Side search ... for anyone else if they would like to implement the same functionality on their DataTable.

```
$sWhere = "";
if ($_GET['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    $words = explode(" ",$_GET['sSearch']);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($words); $j++) {

        if ($words[$j] != "") {
            $sWhere .= "(";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {

                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($words[$j]) . "%' OR ";

            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
            $sWhere .= ") AND ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -4);
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```